# How to set manual default image, if image is not available on my site using js?

Tags: javascript, image, angularjs

I want to set manual dummy image if particular image is not available on website. Also how to set if that image is deleted on server or not available, in that case also i need to display default image using JS.

Comment: As pointed out by @Axel, please update the status of the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is cross-browser, vanilla `JavaScript` and comes along without any ugly `onerror=""` markup:

```js
var sPathToDefaultImg = 'http://lorempixel.com/150/100/abstract/2/Placeholder/';

var replaceImageWithPlaceholderIfNotAvail = function( domImg ) {

  // sanitize domImg
  if ( !domImg || !domImg.nodeName || domImg.nodeName != 'IMG' ) {
    // get all images from DOM
    aImg = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
    i    = aImg.length;
    if ( i ) {
      while ( i-- ) {
        replaceImageWithPlaceholderIfNotAvail( aImg[i] );
      }
    }
    return;
  }

  // here is where the magic happens
  oImg         = new Image();       // create new Image
  oImg.onerror = function() {       // assign onerror
    domImg.src = sPathToDefaultImg; // handler function
  };
  oImg.src     = domImg.src;        // set src of new Image

};

// now you can use the function on "auto pilot"
replaceImageWithPlaceholderIfNotAvail()

// or feed with any domImage you like to evaluate
// replaceImageWithPlaceholderIfNotAvail( domCustomImg )
```

```html
Available: <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png" alt="notavail1.jpg"><br>

Not Available: <img src="notavail1.jpg" alt="notavail2.jpg"><br>

Available: <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png" alt="notavail1.jpg"><br>

Not Available: <img src="notavail2.jpg" alt="notavail4.jpg">
```

[CODEPEN:](http://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/giEvC?editors=001)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: Here is a custom directive version of this answer. I believe it is the best "angular"-approach. It still depends on the service defined in the original answer:

```
app.directive('imageOrDefault', function (Utils) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs);
            Utils.isImage(attrs.imageOrDefault).then(function(result) {
                attrs.$set('src', result);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

You can use it in your markup as follows:

```
<img image-or-default="http://r.llb.be/img/search-418.png" height="42" width="42">
```

[Here is a plunkr of this version.](http://plnkr.co/edit/4fWVsA4h7Czt6WZpjWBK)

---

**Initial answer**:

You can use the ng-src directive to do that and a service to test if the image actually exists. [Here is an example of working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fLMKAnffnEsMMXp7H5x5) you can adapt to fit your exact needs.

There is an `isImage()`-function which will test an URL and returns a `promise`. If the URL is a valid image path, the `promise` is `resolved` with that URL. If it is not, the `promise` will be `resolved` with your default image path.

```
app.factory('Utils', function($q) {
    return {
        isImage: function(src) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var image = new Image();
            image.onerror = function() {
                deferred.resolve('yourDefaultImagePath');
            };
            image.onload = function() {
                deferred.resolve(image.src);
            };
            image.src = src;

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

In the markup, I am using `ng-src`-directive to wait for the `resolve` of the `promise` before setting the `src`-attribute.

```
<img ng-src="{{result}}" height="42" width="42">
```

The `isImage()`-function is called from a `controller`:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Utils) {
    $scope.test = function() {
        Utils.isImage($scope.source).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $scope.result = result;
        });
    };
});
```

This solution can be easily adapted to a custom directive. Let me know if you are interested in this approach.

The solution was adapted from: [Angular js - isImage( ) - check if it's image by url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423057)

Comment: I have completed the answer. rgds

Comment: So you post nothing but "You can use the ng-src directive to do that." and then come back 40 some-odd minutes later to write a *useful* answer? Due respect, next time I'd wait to post until you can post something useful.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that. I was on my smartphone and then came back to answer properly using a real keyboard.

Comment: So this works by proactively loading the image in a separate `Image` object, then if that succeeds, assigning that same source to the target image, using a default image if not. Neat! But...where does the image path come from? Originally, I mean? The code seems to be using `$scope.source` (which it passes into `isImage`, which uses it as the `src`). Where does that come from?

Comment: If you look at the plunkr, it comes from an 'input'. I will update the answer with a custom directive which I believe is the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can go with the approach below:

```
var $defaultImage = '...location of default image..';
```

and then check the image before loading using the ternary operator:

```
var $src = empty($src) ? $src : defaultImage; // dummy code
```

or create a function that will check and return a default image if an image does not exist:

```
checkImageExist($loc)  {
    check for $loc 
    if $loc is undefined or null then return $defaulImage
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
    return true;
}
<img src="image.png" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

or:

```
$("img").error(function () {
  $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "broken.gif");
});
```

Comment: Your second example has a timing problem: The `error` event may have fired **before** you hooked it.

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't help with events that happen **before** your code runs.