# angular custom filter to check if image exists

Tags: angularjs, django, image, filter

I want to display a user profile image if it exists;  else show default font awesome icon.
The profile picture name is an **unique number** and the extensions can be of following types `(jpg, jpeg, png, gif and etc).`

**What i have done so far**

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <p> {{user.name}} </p>
    <img ng-src="{{('/media/upload/' + user.id + '.jpg')}}" onerror="this.src='/media/upload/default.jpeg'" height="80px" width="80px"/>
</div>
```

Right now it only shows image with an **ext** `.jpg.`

**How can i create a custom filter to check if image is available in following extensions  `(jpg, jpeg, png, gif)`and show font awesome icon if it doesn't?**

Any help and feedback are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423057/angular-js-isimage-check-if-its-image-by-url

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any filter in order to achieve that, just make a default src:

```
<img ng-src="{{('/media/upload/' + user.id + '.jpg')}}" src="/media/upload/default.jpeg" height="80px" width="80px"/>
```

The ngSrc directive whould replace the source only if available

In order to test all possible extensions, I would write a directive:

```
app.directive('multiSrc', function($q) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { user: '=' },
    link: function(scope, element) {

      console.log(scope.user);

      var image = new Image();
      var _ext = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];
      function _loadExt(index) {
        if(index >= _ext.length) {
          return;
        }
        _tryLoading(_ext[index])
        .then(function(successImage) {
          element[0].src = successImage.src;
        }, function() {
         return _loadExt(index + 1);
        });
      }
      function _tryLoading(extension) {
        var _defer = $q.defer();
        image.src = '/media/upload/' + scope.user.id + '.' + extension;
        image.onerror = function() {
          _defer.reject();
        };
        image.onload = function() {
          _defer.resolve(angular.copy(image));
        }
        return _defer.promise;
      }
      return _loadExt(0);
   }
 };
});
```

## Edit

This is showing one way to implement it. But it IS NOT best practice at all.

The way this should be done, is when the user upload an image, save the path in the database (within the user object usually), then just request the registered path.

Comment: Well you're repeating me! How can i check if image exist in extensions such as: jpg, jpeg, png, gif and etc? The default src is not an optimal solutions!

Comment: Thanks Kobi! How to use this directive in template?

Comment: <img multi-src user="user" src="/media/upload/default.jpeg" height="80px" width="80px"/>

Comment: `+ scope.user.id +` can't read property of undefined! Pretty close! Thanks @Kobi Cohen

Comment: I don't know why it's undefined, here is a working plunkr https://embed.plnkr.co/hbMprRxYk8xCdgeSAvjH/. also, I've edited the answer after debugging the code. take a look

Comment: you have created  `$scope.user = {id: '4656543'}` in controller, but in my case the `user.id` comes from template. How can i pass user.id as an argument from template to directory?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. you have the users array in the controller, right? updated the plunkr

Comment: Thanks Kobin! One thing i realised is that when image doesn't exist then it send multiple request for image with different extensions. http://tinypic.com/r/2rms7m0/9. Is there way to minimise number of requests?

Comment: I don't think so. If you want to check that image exist then you have to send request for every extension. see the updated answer

Comment: The approach you mentioned (saving image path in db) sounds promising