# How to check the image in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a issue like that, I responsible for development application, so I can not control the database in Amazon, the database depends on another team. I got 2 url img.

Url1: 
'https://aclub-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/1460788549143.jpg' return no image.

Url2: 'https://aclubproduction.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/thebooking_beautyhouse_13.jpg' return right image.
So when I bind the link how can I check it's the image or not. Need help !!! Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423057/angular-js-isimage-check-if-its-image-by-url

Comment: Thank you a lot :) . This is very helpful with me :) . Thank you again.